# Automatic scroll view in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an image scroll view, I import image from remote server but I want to scroll the image automatically, help me how to scroll the image automatically

my xaml code for image scroll view

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="ImgScrollViewer" 
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="ImagesSP"
                 ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control"  
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 Height="124" Width="3690"
                 Loaded="ImagesSP_Loaded_1"   >
         <!--<StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                 <TranslateTransform Y="550"/>
             </StackPanel.RenderTransform-->

         <Image Source="http://technomindtech.com/1tele-pixel.com/ad/logo_banner.jpg"   Width="500" Height="45" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
         <Image Source="http://technomindtech.com/1tele-pixel.com/ad/images.jpeg"   Width="500" Height="45" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
         <Image Source="http://technomindtech.com/1tele-pixel.com/ad/banner.jpg" Width="500" Height="45" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
         <Image Source="http://technomindtech.com/1tele-pixel.com/ad/images.jpeg" Width="500" Height="45" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
         <Image Source="Images\MediumGray.png" Width="480" Height="400" Stretch="Fill" />
     </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

My cs code

```
namespace BogheApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : BasePage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ImagesSP_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the offset where you want to scroll to, and then use `ScrollToVerticalOffset(your_offset_value)` method. Now how you calculate the offset depends on what exactly you want to achieve, so more details is needed to answer this.